# Como puedo mostrar los resultados de una operacion en un datagridview generando una nueva columna?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Deseo generar una nueva columna (llamada "Columna1") mostrando en ella el resultado de cada uno de los valores de una columna ya existente. Con este codigo me sale error diciendo que la Columna1 no existe y no me explico el porque si se supone que se debe de generar antes de realizar las operaciones. Espero me puedan ayudar por favor.

```
     private void btnCalcular_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columna1 = new   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        columna1.HeaderText = "Columna1";
        columna1.Width = 200;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columna1);

        for (int i = 0; i < (this.dataGridView1.RowCount - 1); i++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Columna1"].Value.ToString();

            decimal eff = decimal.Parse(txtEFFsim.Text);
            int fijo2 = int.Parse(lblfijo2.Text); // /100
            decimal resp = eff / fijo2;
            lblresul.Text = resp.ToString();

            int operador = int.Parse(txtQtyOp.Text);
            decimal ratee = int.Parse(txtRate.Text);
            decimal efff = resp; 
            decimal res4 = operador / ratee * efff;
            txt4.Text = res4.ToString(); 

            this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Columna1"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    //List<Person> p1 = new List<Person>();
    //p1.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, EFF_CWS = txt4.Text, });
    //dataGridView1.DataSource = p1;


    private void frmDataGridCalculation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sisIndustrialDataSet2.CWS' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.cWSTableAdapter.Fill(this.sisIndustrialDataSet2.CWS);
    }
}}
```

UPDATE: Ya genero la columna, solo me falta rellenarla con los resultados que obtenga calculando los valores que tengo en mi columna ya existente. Me da error en la siguiente linea:

```
  this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Columna1"].Value.ToString();
```

El error dice: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

El problema con el código que pones es que no le estás dando nombre a la columna, solo pones un texto al header. Prueba a añadir `columna1.Name = "Columna1";` antes de `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columna1);`. Con eso ya no debería lanzarte ese error.

Comment: Efectivamente ya no me lanza ese error, pero ahora me lanza otro con el mensaje de: An unhandled exception of type 'system.NullReferenceException'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Me señala esta linea: this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Columna1"].Value.ToString();

Comment: Obviamente,ya que estas consultando el value de ´Columna1´ antes de darle ningun valor,con lo que es nulo. El código no tiene mucho sentioo,ya que en ningun momento das valor a la columna que has creado.

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con eso por favor?

Comment: Realiza una nueva pregunta,explicando  exactamente que datos debe tener la nueva columna.